# Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables

Tags: debian, kernel, systemd, inotify

This is fragment of [`journalctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Journal) result:

```
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd-sysctl[329]: Couldn't write '65536' to 'fs/inotify/max_user_watches': Input/output error
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd-sysctl[329]: Couldn't write '50000000' to 'net/core/rmem_max': Input/output error
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd-sysctl[329]: Couldn't write '1048576' to 'net/core/wmem_max': Input/output error
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd[1]: Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables.
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host kernel: systemd-sysctl wrote to max_user_watches when file position was not 0!
                             This will not be supported in the future. To silence this
                             warning, set kernel.sysctl_writes_strict = -1
```

[`systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Basic_systemctl_usage) result:

```
root@Host:~# systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service
* systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-01-09 12:37:26 CET; 32min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysctl.service(8)
           man:sysctl.d(5)
  Process: 329 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 329 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd-sysctl[329]: Couldn't write '65536' to 'fs/inotify/max_user_watches': Input/output error
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd-sysctl[329]: Couldn't write '50000000' to 'net/core/rmem_max': Input/output error
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd-sysctl[329]: Couldn't write '1048576' to 'net/core/wmem_max': Input/output error
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 09 12:37:26 Host systemd[1]: Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables.
```

What those logs are all about? I want to get rid of these error messages. How can I do it?

Comment: Do these files (e.g. `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`) exist? Maybe that depends on the kernel configuration. As files cannot be created in `/proc` that would cause an error.

Comment: Yes, they exist. `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches /proc/sys/net/core/{rmem_max,wmem_max}` returns `65536 50000000 1048576`.

Comment: Can you write to them, too? (`echo foo>/proc/...`)

Comment: Yes, I can with no problem.